# Wordpress permalink added second time

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I have my permalinks like the following:

> /%category%/%postname%

However, I once posted a blogpost. I later deleted it, but then again I added it again.
It made a permalink with "-2" behind it, or e.g.:

> www.myadress.com/category/post-2

If I change the permalink to

> www.myadress.com/category/post

It automatically changes it back to

> www.myadress.com/category/post-2

Is there a way I can fix this without the redirection plugin? The previous posts don't exist anymore...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the post from the trash. WP looks to the trash to prevent duplicate permalinks, and until that post is deleted, you will get the "-2" type permalinks.

Comment: ok that's pretty easy, I just didn't know this happened, haha :)
Thanks a lot!